# List Column Names in a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to create code that will return all the column names in a table that I can use for other purposes.  I have this code written.

```
DECLARE @SQLCommand VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = 'ship_to_ud'

SET @SQLCommand = 
'DECLARE @SelTable VARCHAR(50)
SET @SelTable = ' + '''' +  @TableName +  '''' + '
SELECT
     tables.name AS TableName
    ,all_columns.name AS ColumnName

FROM sys.all_columns
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON sys.all_columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types ON sys.all_columns.user_type_id =                 
sys.types.user_type_id 
WHERE sys.tables.name = @SelTable
ORDER BY all_columns.name'

EXEC(@SQLCommand)
```

I would like to add a column that shows TableName.ColumnName, but the syntax defies me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add `,tables.name + ''.'' + all_columns.name` to the select list?  Wrap the table/column name in `quotename()` if any require escaping.

Comment: Oh so simple.  I tried many harder things!  This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No need for dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @TableName = 'Sample_Table'

SELECT t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_COLUMN = t.TABLE_NAME+'.'+c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t
CROSS JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
AND c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName;
```

Results:

```
TABLE_NAME        COLUMN_NAME   TABLE_COLUMN
----------------- ------------- ----------------------------
Sample_Table      Incident      Sample_Table.Incident
Sample_Table      Location      Sample_Table.Location
Sample_Table      Order_Num     Sample_Table.Order_Num
Sample_Table      Item          Sample_Table.Item
Sample_Table      Shift         Sample_Table.Shift
Sample_Table      Team_Member   Sample_Table.Team_Member
Sample_Table      Team_Mem_ID   Sample_Table.Team_Mem_ID
```

Note that I'm using a table I have locally called "sample table." Also note that I'm not addressing the table's schema but, if you look at the tables I'm using (there's also some sys tables that provide this info) that will be easy to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alan Burstein there is no need for dynamic sql here. I personally prefer to go to the sys tables instead as the information_schemas are not always up to date and I never remember which ones are and which ones aren't. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
SET @TableName = 'YourTableName'

select TableName = t.name
    , ColumnName = c.name
    , FullName = t.name + '.' + c.name
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = @TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'ship_to_ud'

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName, null, 1)
```